# JavaScript always returning true even when it's not

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

This is probably the weirdest JavaScript issue ever:

```
$('div.GiftContainer').live('click', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    var price = $(this).attr('data-price');
    if (!self.hasClass('selected')) {
        if (price <= MyCredits) { // always returns true
            alert('OK');
            self.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        } else {
            alert('MOO!');
        }
    } else {
        self.removeClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Returns true even when I added `console.log(price + ' ' + MyCredits);` right before the condition and price was smaller than MyCredits.

What could it be...

Comment: Have you tried parseInt, or one of the functions from that family?  Maybe it's parsing it as a string, or something to that effect.

Comment: yup, that fixed it :) please answer my question so that I can mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Is `MyCredits` a string or a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try parseInt().  That should fix it to make sure that they're being properly interpreted by JS.

Answer (score 0):

There are types in JavaScript. This can get confusing because it is a dynamic language. Try the following to ensure both values are `numbers`:

`if (parseInt(price, 10) <= parseInt(MyCredits, 10))`

Here is some more information: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Variables_and_Types

Answer (score -1):

> price was smaller than MyCredits

Well in that case `price <= MyCredits` is true. So there's nothing wrong.